# div.style.display not working when declared inside a function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add an EventListener on  so that when  is clicked it should hide the  & vice versa when clicked so i wanted to use classList.toggle to toggle by adding & removing function named "hidden"

```
var p1 = document.getElementById("p1")
var h2 = document.querySelectorAll("h2")[0]
h2.addEventListener("click",function(){
p1.classList.add("hidden")
})

function hidden(div){
div.style.display="none";
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling the `hidden` function?

Comment: `if (div.style.display=="none") { div.style.display="block" } else { div.style.display="none" }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you are not calling hidden function. If you want to call it then remove `classList.add`

```js
var p1 = document.getElementById("p1")
var h2 = document.querySelectorAll("h2")[0];

function hidden(elem) {
  elem.style.display = "none";
}
h2.addEventListener("click", function() {

  hidden(p1)
})
```

```css
h2 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2> I am h2</h2>
<div id="p1"> I am p1</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var p1 = document.getElementById("p1")
var h2 = document.querySelectorAll("h2")[0]
h2.addEventListener("click",function(){
    p1.classList.toggle("hidden"); // changed to toggle instead of add
})

// this is not needed as the function above toggles the class name hidden
// on the element itself
//function hidden(div){
//div.style.display="none";
//}
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>If you click me I can toggle P1</h2>
<p id="p1">This is P1</p>
```

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt I have added dummy HTML so the snippet works